# Need assistance on function to determine largest list Haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to create a function that reads from a list of courses (such as the one shown below), and return which courses has the largest number of programming languages.

Here is the list

```
progLanguages = 
     [ ("CptS121" , ["C"]), 
     ("CptS122" , ["C++"]), 
     ("CptS223" , ["C++"]), 
     ("CptS233" , ["Java"]), 
     ("CptS321" , ["C#"]), 
     ("CptS322" , ["Python", "JavaScript"]), 
     ("CptS355" , ["Haskell", "Python", "PostScript", "Java"]), 
     ("CptS360" , ["C"]), 
     ("CptS370" , ["Java"]), 
     ("CptS315" , ["Python"]), 
     ("CptS411" , ["C", "C++"]), 
     ("CptS451" , ["Python", "C#", "SQL"]), 
     ("CptS475" , ["Python", "R"]) 
     ]
```

It needs to be compatible with the following

```
The type of the max_count function should be compatible with one of the following:   
max_count :: [(a1, [a2])] -> (a1, Int) 
max_count :: Foldable t => [(a1, t a2)] -> (a1, Int)
```

So far, I have attempted the following code

```
max_count [] = error "bad"
max_count [x] = x
max_count (x:xs) = x max_helper (max_count xs)
     where
     max_helper (a,b) (a',b')
          | length b > length b' = (a, length b)
          | otherwise = (a', length b')
```

This has not worked in the slightest, and I am at a blank for what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean `max_helper x (max_count xs)` instead? What is the error? You seem to be on the right track.

Comment: first, it's ``x `max_helper` (max_count xs)``. second, since the result of `max_helper` is the result of `max_count`, that must be the type of `max_helper`'s second argument as well. that's how you get to the working version: don't try to remeasure `length` of what is the result of a previous `length` call -- just use that result. you could instead return something which is measurable by `length`, but this would repeat the `length` calculation over and over, potentially, wasting computational effort.

Answer (score 3):

Your main problem is that you are assuming that `max_helper` takes a class/language-*list* pair as its second argument, when it takes a class/language-*count* as returned by `max_count`. (You are also incorrectly applying `x` to `max_helper`, rather than the other way around.

```
max_count :: [(a1, [a2])] -> (a1, Int)
max_count [] = error "bad"
max_count [(a, b)] = (a, length b)
max_count (x:xs) = max_helper x (max_count xs)
        where
        max_helper (a,bs) (a', b')
            | length bs > b' = (a, length bs)
            | otherwise = (a', b')
```

---

However, you can define this more declaratively. First, you don't care about the actual languages, only their count. Replace the lists with their lengths by taking advantage of the fact that `fmap f (a, b) == (a, f b)`:

```
> map (fmap length) progLanguages
[("CptS121",1),("CptS122",1),("CptS223",1),("CptS233",1),("CptS321",1),("CptS322",2),("CptS355",4),("CptS360",1),("CptS370",1),("CptS315",1),("CptS411",2),("CptS451",3),("CptS475",2)]
```

Now what you want is the *maximum* of this list, but using a comparison function that ignores the class name and *only* looks at the lengths. You can construct such a function using `Data.Ord.comparing`:

```
-- "b" > "a", but 1 < 2
> comparing snd ("b", 1), ("a", 2)
LT
```

You can use this comparison function with `Data.List.maximumBy`:

```
> import Data.List
> import Data.Ord
> max_count = maximumBy (comparing snd) . map (fmap length)
> max_count progLanguages
("CptS355",4)
> :t max_count
max_count :: Foldable t => [(a1, t a2)] -> (a1, Int)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `foldr` and hold the information of max entry in accumulator variable:

```haskell
maxCount :: Foldable t => [(a1, t a2)] -> (a1, Int)
maxCount [] = error "bad"
maxCount ((c,cs):l) = foldr opr (c, length cs) ((c,cs):l)
  where
    opr (c', xs) (c'', n)
      | length xs > n = (c', length xs)
      | otherwise = (c'', n)
```

I think `error "bad"` is bad practice here, we can use `Maybe`:

```haskell
maxCount' :: Foldable t => [(a1, t a2)] -> Maybe (a1, Int)
maxCount' [] = Nothing
maxCount' ((c,cs):l) = Just $ foldr opr (c, length cs) ((c,cs):l)
  where
    opr (c', xs) (c'', n)
      | length xs > n = (c', length xs)
      | otherwise = (c'', n)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, function `foldr` is best. Your approach is also feasible. It is only necessary to thoroughly **understand the error messages** of the compiler. In this case, I would advise you not to use the where clause and implement the function `max_helper` globally. I don't know if you intended

```
max_helper1 :: Foldable t => (a1, t a2) -> (a1, Int) -> (a1, Int)
```

or

```
max_helper2 :: (a1, Int) -> (a1, Int) -> (a1, Int)
```

There are many possibilities. The second parameter is good to have the same as the output value of the `max_count`, because of *recursion*.

The left side of the `max_count` can then look like this:

```
max_count (x:xs)
```

or

```
max_count ((x,y):xs)
```

.

The right side could probably contain:

```
max_helper12 ... (max_count xs)
```

The periods must be replaced with `x` or `(x,length y)` according to the variant.

I also noticed that for `max_helper1`, there could be a double calculation of the length, and it isn't efficient in Haskell. Therefore, I would recommend counting only once in where:

```
max_helper1 (a,b) (a',b')
          | b'' > b' = (a, b'')
          | otherwise = (a', b')
  where
    b'' = length b
```

Also, try to correct the termination rule:

> `max_count [(x,y)] = (x,length y)`